# Initializing a field inside an anonymous struct

Tags: go

Given this anonymous struct:

```
var myMap struct {
  list       map[string]string
  someStuff *some.Object
}
```

Can I initialize the `list` and `someStuff` in one declaration?

This doesn't work:

```
var myMap struct {
  list       map[string]string = make(map[string]string)
  someStuff *some.Object = &some.Object{}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var myMap = struct {
  list map[string]string
  str string
}{
  list: map[string]string{"hello":"string"},
  str: "myString",
}
```

You can also do it this way:

```
var myMap = struct {
  list map[string]string
  str string
}{map[string]string{"hello":"string"}, "myString"}
```

And a working example: <kbd>[Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/j1l2epoB_s)</kbd>.

So you declare your structure and then in curly braces you initiate it. (I learned it from [this old go talk](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#3).)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do this. Look at this example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    myMap := struct {
        list       map[string]string
        someStuff interface{}
    }{
        list: make(map[string]string),
        someStuff: 2,
    }

    fmt.Println(myMap)
}
```